# Getting value from Java raw map

Tags: scala

I'm trying to write a function

```
def convert(x: String): String = ...
```

that converts its argument by looking up in a map, and returning `x` if the argument isn't a key in the map.  Unfortunately, the map must be obtained by calling a Java method that returns a raw `Map`:

```
public static Map getMapFromConfiguration() { ... }
```

This is legacy code I can't do anything about.  In this particular case, the keys and values of the returned map will be `String` (and it's OK if the code throws an exception if the keys or values have some other type).  So far, the only way I've been able to get the code to compile is by constructing a new `Map[String,String]`:

```
def convert(x: String): String = {
    val mapFromConfig: scala.collection.mutable.Map[_,_] = JavaClass.getMapFromConfiguration().asScala
    val convertedMap: Map[String,String] = (mapFromConfig map {
        case (key, value) => key.asInstanceOf[String] -> value.asInstanceOf[String] }).toMap
    convertedMap.getOrElse(x, x)
}
```

I've tried various ways to use `get` or `getOrElse` directly on `mapFromConfig`, but haven't found anything that compiles.  Some attempts:

```
    val mapFromConfig: scala.collection.mutable.Map[_ <: Any, _ <: Any] = JavaClass.getMapFromConfiguration().asScala
    mapFromConfig.getOrElse(x, x).asInstanceOf[String]

Type mismtach, expected: _$1, actual: String

    val mapFromConfig: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Any,Any] = JavaClass.getMapFromConfiguration().asScala
    mapFromConfig.getOrElse(x, x).asInstanceOf[String]

error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.mutable.Map[?0,?1] where type ?1, type ?0
 required: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Any,Any]
Note: ?0 <: Any, but trait Map is invariant in type A.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Any`. (SLS 3.2.10)
Note: ?1 <: Any, but trait Map is invariant in type B.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Any`. (SLS 3.2.10)

    val mapFromConfig: java.util.Map[_,_] = JavaClass.getMapFromConfiguration()
    mapFromConfig.getOrDefault(x, x).asInstanceOf[String]

Type mismtach, expected: _$2, actual: String
```

Is there a good way to accomplish what I need without creating an intermediate map?

Comment: I think, your last attempt (with `getOrDefault`) should work if you remove the type annotation

Comment: @Dima If you mean removing `: java.util.Map[_,_]`, I'm getting the same error.

Comment: That sucks. How about changing it to `java.util.Map[Any, Any]`?

Comment: @Dima Now I get an error on `mapFromConfig`.  `java.util.Map[Any,Any]` doesn't conform to expected type `java.util.Map[_,_]`.

Comment: Where is `Map[_,_]`?

Comment: This works for me: `val foo: java.util.Map[Any, Any] = new java.util.HashMap(); foo.getOrDefault("foo", "bar")`

Comment: @Dima Apparently Scala thinks the type of the `getMapFromConfiguration` call (the Java method) is `Map[_,_]`.  That's why this type shows up in the "doesn't conform" message.  The last comment isn't helpful, because I need to get at the result of the Java method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main trick is to cast a non-generic `Map` to explicitly generic `java.util.Map[String, String]`. Code that works for me is

```scala
val map: java.util.Map[String, String] = ScalaToJava.getMapFromConfiguration.asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[String, String]]
println(map.get("key"))
```

Given Java code:

```java
public class ScalaToJava {
    static Map getMapFromConfiguration() {
        HashMap map = new HashMap();
        map.put("key", "value");
        return map;
    }
}
```

Or if you want to convert `map` to the Scala one, you can use something like

```scala
val map = ScalaToJava.getMapFromConfiguration.asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[String, String]].asScala
println(map.get("key"))
```